# How to show progress in a webpage while downloading a file from another server ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

In one of my webpage, the controls are based on values specified in some xml files in another remote server.So I need to download and parse them at page_load() and display the controls.The problem is the xml files are quite large and take lots of time.
So I want to download the xml files using webclient.DownloadFileAsync() method and show the information as how much bytes downloaded.

I have written code to download the files, but don't know how to update the page on DownloadProgressChanged event.I think it require ajax methods.Kindly guide me how to do that.

**aspx page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">   
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>       
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <br />            
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Code behind** (Thanks to another stackoverflow question)

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

   private void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
        }
        // Starts the download
       Label1.Text = "Downloading...";
       DownloadFile();
    }

private void DownloadFile()
{
    if (_downloadUrls.Any())
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new     System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

        var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
        string FileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileName);
        //lblFileName.Text = url;
        return;
    }
    // End of the download
    Label1.Text = "Download Complete";
 }

 void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    DownloadFile();
 }

 void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    //  Label1.Text = percentage.ToString();        
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<string> urls = new List<string>();
    urls.Add("http://abcd.com/1.xml");
    urls.Add("http://abcd.com/2.xml");
    downloadFile(urls);
  }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use JQuery Progressbar.


http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: nice question! Ill reply tonight! Anyway I have a solution for that using jQuery ajax, JQuery progress bar and storing the partial result in the session!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/rrobbins/archive/2008/06/27/file-download-progress-bar.aspx

Comment: Good resource though the files are not there .. :(

Comment: Thanks that it helped you and mark as answer if it really helped you.And the reaources available to download there.

Comment: But my problem is not solved.. the files are not available for download

Comment: Here you have another source to download http://weblogs.asp.net/rrobbins/archive/2008/06/27/file-download-progress-bar.aspx

Comment: I achieved the effect by using pagemethods and one static string variable..almost same approach as your links point out..
this link (http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) also helped me

Comment: @Broam-The second link seems the same with download available you can try that.